# How to display data with pivot in oracle?

Tags: oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I stuck an hours to display the data in weekly result, but I'm always fail to display that. I'm new in pivot.

Please help me.

Thank you!

Sample data need to produce:

```
Data,03/10/2014,200,150,186,172
Data,03/16/2014,144,115,181,157
Data,03/22/2014,130,198,136,393
```

Here's the script:

```
select 'Data,'''
||(
select listagg(SIM_id,''',''') within group (order by 1)
from (
    select distinct substr(dst_channel,1,14) as SIM_id
    from table1
    where dst_channel like 'SIP/item__-%'
)
)
from dual;
select 'Data'
 ||','||dtime_day
 ||','||g1_cnt
 ||','||g2_cnt
 ||','||g3_cnt
 ||','||g4_cnt
 from (
 select 'Data'
      ,to_char(d.dtime_day,'MM/dd/yyyy') as dtime_day
      ,substr(c.dst_channel,1,14) as dst_channel
from table2 d
left join table1
on c.call_date = d.dtime_day
where c.dst_channel like 'SIP/item%'
and c.status like 'ANSWERED%'
and d.dtime_day between trunc(sysdate, 'IW')-(12*7) and trunc(sysdate) -1
)
pivot(
count(dst_channel) as cnt
for dst_channel in (
    'SIP/item01' as g1,'SIP/item02' as g2,'SIP/item03' as g3,'SIP/item04' as g4
    )
 )
order by dtime_day
```

Result of the query above:

```
Data,03/10/2014,147,103,86,76
Data,03/11/2014,144,115,81,57
Data,03/12/2014,130,98,59,39
```

Comment: If you want help with a complex query like this it's reasonable to expect you to prepare an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4) with the appropriate tables declared and filled with enough data to demonstrate the problem. Thanks.

Comment: As a note:  a non-working query can do amazingly little to convey what you want to do.  You should edit your question with sample data and the results that you want to achieve.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i already put sample data in my question

Comment: do also indicate the column name of your data where they came from. try to consider rollup and cube